# integral over $U - 0 $ and $R^2 - \overline{U}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let U be the open set in $R^2 $ consisting of all $x$ with $-1< x<1$. Let $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} $ for $(x,y) \not= 0$. Determine whether f is integrable over $U - 0$ and over $R^2 - \overline{U}$, If so evaluate. 
I am completely lost on how to approach this problem, please be as detailed in your solution\explanation as possible

Comment: By "all $x$ with $-1<x<1$" do you mean all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with  $-1<x<1$, i.e., a strip bounded horizontally but not vertically?  Hint:  try to use polar coordinates.

Comment: @ForgotALot what would the bound for $\theta $ be, we can take r as 0<r<1,, would it be 0 < $\theta$ < $2\pi$ ? Can you please explain why

Comment: You have two potential infinities of the integral to deal with, one for large $r$ ($=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$), the other near $0$.  Polar coordinates will give you a handle on those infinities.  You will then see which of the two integrals, $U\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{U}$, you actually have to evaluate (calculate).

Comment: For U\{(0,0)} the bounds I came up with are $0< r<\infty, \frac{-\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and for $R^2\setminus  \overline{U}$ $1<r< \infty \text{ and } 0 < \theta < 2\pi $